# C++ array bound is not an integer

Tags: c++, array, poo

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que gestiona el ingreso e impresion de datos de empleados de una empresa

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define TECLA_ARRIBA 72
#define TECLA_ABAJO 80
#define ENTER 13

using namespace std;

int cant;

class empleado;

class programa
{
public:
    void cabecera();
    void cantidad_de_empleados();
    int constructordemenues(const char *titulo, const char *opciones[], int n);
    void bibliotecademenues(char opcion);
    void gotoxy(int x,int y);
}
cuerpo;

void programa::cabecera()
{
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";
    cout<<char(201);
    for(int i=0, x=36; i<=x; i++)
        cout<<char(205);
    cout<<char(187);
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t";
    cout<<char(186)<<" <:: Registro de empleados - XYZ ::> "<<char(186);
    cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t";
    cout<<char(200);
    for(int i=0, x=36; i<=x; i++)
        cout<<char(205);
    cout<<char(188);
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t";
}

void programa::cantidad_de_empleados()
{
    cabecera();
    cout<<"> Cantidad de empleados a manejar: ";
    cin>>cant;
}

int programa::constructordemenues(const char *titulo, const char *opciones[],int n)
{
    int opcionSeleccionada = 1;

    int tecla;
    bool repite = true;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cabecera();
        gotoxy(32, 6);
        cout << titulo;
        gotoxy(28, 7 + opcionSeleccionada);
        cout << ">";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            gotoxy(32, 8 + i);
            cout << i + 1 << ") " <<opciones[i];
        }
        do
        {
            tecla = getch();
        }
        while (tecla != TECLA_ARRIBA && tecla != TECLA_ABAJO && tecla != ENTER);
        switch (tecla)
        {
        case TECLA_ARRIBA:
            opcionSeleccionada--;
            if (opcionSeleccionada < 1)
                opcionSeleccionada = n;
            break;

        case TECLA_ABAJO:
            opcionSeleccionada++;
            if (opcionSeleccionada > n)
                opcionSeleccionada = 1;
            break;

        case ENTER:
            repite = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (repite);
    return opcionSeleccionada;
}

void programa::bibliotecademenues(char opcion)
{
    switch(opcion)
    {

    case 'p':
    {
        cantidad_de_empleados();
        bool repite = true;
        int opcion;
        const char *titulo = "> Elija una opcion:";
        const char *opciones[] = {"Ingresar un nuevo empleado","Verificar datos de uno existente","Salir"};
        int n = 3;
        while(repite)
        {
            opcion = constructordemenues(titulo,opciones,n);
            switch (opcion)
            {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                bibliotecademenues('s');
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case 's': //menu de salida
    {
        bool repite = true;
        int opcion;
        const char *titulo = "> Desea salir del sistema? ";
        const char *opciones[] =
        {
            "Si","No"
        };
        int n = 2;
        while (repite)
        {
            opcion = constructordemenues(titulo,opciones,n);
            switch (opcion)
            {
            case 1:
                exit(0);
                break;
            case 2:
                repite = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}

void programa::gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y= y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}

int main()
{
    cuerpo.bibliotecademenues('p');
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}

class empleado
{
private:
    string nombres;
    string telefono;
public:
    void ingresar_datos();
    void imprimir_datos();
}
persona[cant];
```

Mi problema es que quisiera asignar un valor a la variable cant, pero al hacerlo el compilador me tira este error "*array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token*"

Extra: tambien me gustaria poder declarar la clase programa y ponerla despues del main pero no me reconoce el objeto cuerpo al hacerlo ¿Como le hago?

Comment: Has agregado demasiado código y se hace difícil la lectura. Además, no es fácilmente compilable. Lee [mcve] para una futura ocasión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema se puede reducir a lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

int cant;

class empleado;

int main()
{
    cant = 5;
    std::cout << "Hola!";
    return 0;
}

class empleado
{
private:
    std::string nombres;
    std::string telefono;
public:
    void ingresar_datos();
    void imprimir_datos();
}
persona[cant];
```

Con `persona[cant];` entendemos que tu intención es definir un array de 5 elementos y es cuando el compilador te muestra el error

> main.cpp:23:13: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
>    persona[cant];

Lo que te está diciendo es que en el momento de **COMPILAR** la aplicación, la variable `cant` no tiene ningún valor, por lo que le es imposible conocer el tamaño que debe tener.

Lo que te pide es que definas esta variable como `const`, para que el compilador sepa que valor tiene esta variable en el momento de su compilación:

```
int const cant = 5;
```

Sin embargo, esto no te va a servir de ayuda, pues entiendo que lo que necesitas es **definir un array *dinámico* de objetos de tipo `empleado`**.

Lo que te recomiendo es que utilices un simple vector de empleados:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<empleado> personas;
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

Usando el diseño de tu aplicación, te pongo un ejemplo de usar un vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class empleado
{
private:
    std::string nombre;
    std::string telefono;
public:

    void ingresar_datos();
    void imprimir_datos();
};

void empleado::ingresar_datos()
{
    std::cout << "Introduce nombre: ";
    std::cin >> nombre;
    std::cout << "Introduce teléfono: ";
    std::cin >> telefono;
}

void empleado::imprimir_datos()
{
    std::cout << "Nombre: " << nombre << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Teléfono: " << telefono << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Creando datos\n";

    empleado e1;
    std::vector<empleado> listaEmpleados;

    // Solicitas el ingreso de datos
    e1.ingresar_datos();

    // Lo agregas al vector de empleados
    listaEmpleados.push_back(e1);

    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo te hago unas consideraciones importantes a mi criterio:

- Yo cambiaría el diseño de tu clase empleado, creando un constructor de inicialización de la variable nombre y teléfono:

  `empleado( std::string nombre, std::string telefono ) : nombre(nombre), telefono(telefono) {};`
- Haría la introducción de cada campo fuera de la clase y utilizaría el constructor en lugar de pedirle el objeto que solicitara "rellenarse" el mismo

Sobre el resto de tu código, es demasiado amplio y creo que queda fuera de tu duda original.

Comment: comprendes bien mi problema David, lo que busco es definir un array dinamico de objetos tipo empleado, pero no comprendo la solucion que propones, si puedes poner un codigo aplicado con tu solucion lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Cierra si te sirvió de utilidad

Comment: me fue util la sugerencia de constructores, pero el problema lo resolvi de otra forma, de todas formas gracias por ayudarme

Comment: Hola, estudie como funcionan los vectores, la verdad tu solucion es mucho mejor, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para arreglar este problema (al menos en mi caso) cree la variable que contiene el tamaño del arreglo de objetos y despues declare el arreglo dentro del main, asi me lo reconoce sin problemas ej:

```
int main()
{
   int con;
   cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ";
   cin>>con;
   cout<<"\n";
   empleado persona[con];
   return 0;
}
```